# auto complete text view making list go up

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

i want to make my auto complete text view suggestion to go up and not down i have this layout which makes it go down

> simple_dropdown_item_1line

is there any layout that can make it go up?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Sentence");
    alert.setMessage("type only words you taught him!!!");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    //final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    //alert.setView(input);
    // Get a reference to the AutoCompletet in the layout
//  AttributeSet a =Resources.Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(a, playnum, cheight, cheight)  ;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mywordstring);
    final AutoCompleteTextView t =new AutoCompleteTextView(v.getContext());
    // Get the string array
    //String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
    // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompletet 

    t.setAdapter(adapter);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    t.setThreshold(1);
    t.setDropDownHeight(cheight/2);
    //t.setDropDownWidth(cwidth/2);
    t.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark);
    alert.setView(t);
```

also for some reason the completion dont appear after spaces

Comment: i would really love some help here

Comment: theres no solutions to this?